# Need help for sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to find a solution for the following exercise: 
I have this table:

```
maker   model   type
E   2010    laptop
E   1013    pc
E   1012    pc
D   2007    laptop
D   1011    pc
D   1010    pc
D   1009    pc
C   3006    printer
C   3003    printer
```

And i need to find Manufacturers of at least 2 different computers (Pc) at a speed of at least 700.
I have tried a several queries but nothing. Would you tell me a how i have to write this query to be true?

The speed column is in another table named PC where we have model,speed,price and etc I have tried a few queries like this one:

```
select maker from product p
join pc pc on pc.model=p.model
where pc.speed>700
group by maker
having count(distinct p.model)>=2;
```

But it doesn't work properly and i don't know what to do! I will be more then thankful if you can help me!

Comment: I can't see a speed column. Is it the Model?

Comment: Given that your sample data has no information about speed, we can't help you.

Comment: In addition to the lacking speed info, we'd also like to see at least one of the queries you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to return the `Manufacturers of at least 2 different computers` you need to make sure that the models you count are different. Otherwise you could be counting twice the same model (unless there is uniqueness in the [maker, model] pair)

```
select maker from table
where type = 'pc' and model >= 700      -- Should be Speed in this line?
group by maker
having count(distinct model) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by `maker` and filter the results accordingly:

```
SELECT   maker
FROM     my_table
WHERE    type = 'pc' AND model >= 700
GROUP BY maker
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85530/1/0).

Comment: I forgot to tell that i have another table with PC info from where i am taking information about the speed. I make a join with this table to make a where clause for the speed, but i probably i made a mistake when i trying to find different models and more then 2 in product table!